# SQL Server, one table with data -> insert into table with a foreign key, and that foreign key table has to be filled also

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-insert

For a school project I have made a `.csv` import via C# and imported all the data from the file into a table containing only strings. We have to do some validation on the imported code using SQL server which I have already done. The table I have imported my data into looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StoreData]
(
    [StoreName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Street] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [StreetNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ZipCode] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TelephoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

With this table filled, I have to Insert this data into the `[Stores]` table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stores]
(
    [Id] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,             <- GUID 
    [Name] [nvarchar](85) NOT NULL,
    [CountryCode] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [AddressId] [nvarchar](450) NULL           <- FK to [Address] Table
)
```

And here is my problem, the `[Stores]` contains a FK to the `[Addresses]` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses]
(
    [Id] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,             <- GUID
    [Street] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [HouseNumber] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [Addition] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ZipCode] [nvarchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](85) NOT NULL,
    [SeriesIndicationStart] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SeriesIndicationEnd] [int] NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Addresses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

So now I have `[StoreData]` that contains the data I have to put in `[Addresses]` and in `[Stores]`, and I have to keep in mind that the FK has to be set in [Stores]. This is our first database semester, and I am clueless, and tomorrow is the deadline..

I hope someone can help me out.. thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the difference between Country and CountryCode?  Suppose a store has addresses in multiple countries, then what?  Is the DDL of the 2 target tables fixed or could you change it?  The biggest issue is there isn't an obvious way to reproduce the order of the addresses for a given store.  Did you load every column of data present in the CSV?

Comment: Is StoreName unique?  (hint the key here is to have a key on StoreData).

Comment: @SteveC Country and CountryCode is the same thing. In the .csv file it is called country, but I named it countryCode becuas it is written as (NL, DE, ..). The DDL is fixed.. See it as a most simple project where we dont have to account that sort of stuff.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes store name is unique.

Comment: I would firstly insert the distinct addresses into the address table and then I would insert into the store table with an insert select joining storedata with addreses to get the AddressId. Why are you not using a Identity column for the ID's?